# VSCode debugger does not highlight errors as precise as eclipse does in Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I really want to make Java programming within Vscode work and worthwhile and so far it looks pretty good, got all the recommended extensions up and running, however I figured that vsc is not highlighting errors like convert errors as nicely as eclipse does.

Is that a settings issue or do I need another extension for this?

VSC Extension that I got at the moment for Java: 
- Debugger for Java
- Java Extension Pack
- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
- Maven for Java
- Checkstyle for Java
- Java Test Runner

However I am not using Test Runner and Maven so far, could this be the reason?

I think the right term would be a linter, but for Java, which does red lines under my code when it sees errors.

Comment: Is there really a question here, how can we know what "nicely" means to you and recommend anything.

Comment: it does not mark my code AT ALL, so basically this linting function is what I am looking for. I hope that someone who worked longer with Java in vsc could perhaps answer this.